Sympy does not calculate improper integrals with hermite polynomials
I am running a classic Quantum Harmonic Oscillator problem, and thus I need to find integrals containing Hermite polynomials. Unfortunately, sympy does not return a result for the integrals containing them, except for the very simple case of orthogonality
In the trivial case mentioned above, I truly get, the expected Kronecker delta:
import sympy as sm 
pi = sm.pi
x = sm.Symbol('x') 
n = sm.Symbol('n', integer=True,positive=True) 
k = sm.Symbol('k')
psi = sm.hermite(n,x)*sm.exp(-x*2/2)*pi**(-1/4)*(1/sm.sqrt(sm.factorial(n)*2**n))
sm.integrate(psi.subs({n:i})*psi.subs({n:j}),(x,-sm.oo,sm.oo))

The last line really results in \delta_{ij} for many different integer values of i and j, I checked,so at least this integral is computable.
So, to get to the main problem, when I run lines such as:
phi = sm.integrate(psi*sm.exp(-sm.I*k*x),(x,-sm.oo,+sm.oo))*(1/sm.sqrt(2*pi)) 
sm.integrate(psi*psi*x,(x,-sm.oo,+sm.oo)) 
sm.integrate(psi*psi*x*x,(x,-sm.oo,+sm.oo)) 
sm.integrate(phi*k*phi,(k,-sm.oo,+sm.oo)) 
sm.integrate(phi*k*k*phi,(k,-sm.oo,+sm.oo)) , 

it refuses to calculate the integrals. I have also tried using a tolerance as the integral limit, and the command sm.Integral insted of sm.integrate(), but the situation remains. Any help would be more than welcome, and thank you in advance

Your code is broken. What is i, j? Delta_ij is on the rhs of = and operators are missing in the definition of psi. Please paste your code in an interpreter to check.

I meant it as a way than when I checked it against many values of i and j it truly resulted in a Kronecker delta.
